# ASP.NET 'WebForm_PostBackOptions' is undefined error - Only occurs in server, for one page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-2.0

I've been assigned to fix some issues in our legacy system, which is created using Asp.net 2.0. This application is created to run on IE lower versions (v5.0/v7.0/v9.0).

The issue is, when I tried to click on a link of the page, it gives me the error `'WebForm_PostBackOptions' is undefined`. For the naked eye, it seems like the click event is not even triggering, so, I can only see the error when I open the console (F12) of IE.

[image: IE Console Error]

The problem is, this works fine in my local environment, and even in another testing environment. 
This only happens in our Live server, only in one section of a single page; make me wonder whether there are any version incompatibilities.

below are my relevant .aspx and .cs codes.

.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater Runat="server" ID="rptCustomers">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Runat="server" ID="lblCustomerID" Visible="False" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%>' />
        <asp:LinkButton Runat="server" ID="lbtnCustomer" CommandName="SELECT CUSTOMER" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name")%>' /><br>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

.cs

```
private void rptCustomers_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "SELECT CUSTOMER")
    {
        if(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCustomerID")).Text == "")
        {
            ViewState["Customer"] = Guid.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewState["Customer"] = new Guid(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCustomerID")).Text);
        }
        RebindData();
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could give me some kind of a solution, or an explanation for this.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found an answer for this if anyone faces the same issue one day. It's something to do with the server IIS, and after I added the tag `CausesValidation ="false"` to my code segment, the issue was resolved.